# converting to string from sqlite tuple

Tags: python, string, sqlite, tuples

When I retrieve data from my database, it is returned in the following format however I need it simply as just the text on its own:

```
[(u'milk',)]
[(7,)]
```

i have tried converting it into a string etc so that I could use a for loop to iterate through it and pop off the unneeded characters but nothing has worked

Here is my code:

```
def retShopping(db):
    item = []
    quan = []
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT quantity FROM Shopping''')
        hold = str(cursor.fetchall())
        quan.append(hold)
        cursor.execute('''SELECT item FROM Shopping''')
        hold2 = str(cursor.fetchall())
        item.append(hold2)
        print(item[0])
        print(quan[0])
```

I am hoping to be able to just end up with the strings`'milk'` and `'7'` so that I am able to use them in print statements.

Comment: You have lists of tuples of values. Read up on how to access list and tuple elements. Also 7 is an integer, not a string.

Comment: And python3 is much more pretty that python2.

Comment: Try item[0][0].
having (xxx,) means it's a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def retShopping(db):
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as db:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT quantity FROM Shopping''')
        hold = cursor.fetchall()
        print(hold[0][0])
        cursor.execute('''SELECT item FROM Shopping''')
        hold2 = cursor.fetchall()
        print(hold2[0][0])
```